# Offtopic discussion rephrased, may it be reopened?

Tags: support, scope, off-topic, closed-questions, specific-question

I rephrased the questions from [Remastering cartoons towards vector animations](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32942/remastering-cartoons-towards-vector-animations) is this good enough to be reopened?

Answer (score 1):

No - you are still asking a question that doesn't meet our site requirements. Please read our [about] and [ask] pages.

We do not do recommendations of products or services.

If you are searching for projects, Google will do a much better search than this site can.

Comment: What do you recommend to search for then? Since the first two hits on Google are actually the closed discussion.